# Select Image or Take Photo and go to new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using Fusuma https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma and in Fusuma is it possible to make minor modifications with code so after selecting photo or taking it it takes me to new view controller for example uploadViewcontroller where is selected image presented ( later it would be good to make another view after taking photo to confirm it or retake)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can implement `FusumaDelegate`'s method `fusumaImageSelected` (or `fusumaMultipleImageSelected`, write there any navigation code (like segues, navigationController's pushViewController method or viewControllers' present) and pass your image through it.

```
import UIKit
import Fusuma

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var photoLibraryButton: UIButton!

    let fusuma = FusumaViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fusuma.delegate = self
        fusuma.allowMultipleSelection = true

    }

    @IBAction
    func showPhotoLibrary() {
        self.present(fusuma, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension ViewController: FusumaDelegate {
    func fusumaImageSelected(_ image: UIImage, source: FusumaMode) {

        let vc = UploadViewController()
        vc.image = image

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }

    func fusumaMultipleImageSelected(_ images: [UIImage], source: FusumaMode) {
        let vc = UploadViewController()
        guard let firstImage = images.first else { return }
        vc.image = firstImage

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func fusumaVideoCompleted(withFileURL fileURL: URL) {

    }

    func fusumaCameraRollUnauthorized() {

    }

}
```

And then in UploadViewController you can do whatever you want:

```
import UIKit

class UploadViewController: ViewController {

    public var image = UIImage()
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.frame)
        imageView.image = self.image

        view.addSubview(imageView)

    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer, now it works with multiple too. Difference between single and multiple selections is that in multiple you get an array of images.

Answer (score 0):

Just Write your navigation code in `image selection  delegate`

if you support `allowMultipleSelection = true`

then write navigation code there

```
func fusumaMultipleImageSelected(_ images: [UIImage], source: FusumaMode) {

            print("Number of selection images: \(images.count)")

            // your navigation code
            let viewController = UIViewController()
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

if you support one selection `allowMultipleSelection = false`

Write you navigation code there

```
func fusumaImageSelected(_ image: UIImage, source: FusumaMode) {

        switch source {

        case .camera:

            print("Image captured from Camera")

        case .library:

            print("Image selected from Camera Roll")

        default:

            print("Image selected")
        }

        // set you controller there

        let viewController = UIViewController()
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      //   imageView.image = image
    }
```

Comment: Nope its redirecting on the same ViewController not anotherViewController @Abdelahad Darwish

Comment: i write set your    **// set your controller there** we just write concept and solution

Comment: I already set it not working `let viewController = imageFiltersViewController()
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: `imageFiltersViewController`  where is nib file or storybord controller

Comment: in the same project or main storyboard

Comment: `imageFiltersViewController() `  you should create from nib or storybord